# Angular - Problema ao passar mensagem entre componentes

Tags: angular

Boa noite pessoal.

Estou, por motivo de estudos, fazendo um CRUD simples para gerenciamento de autores. Empaquei na parte de enviar uma mensagem de sucesso ao cadastrar um novo autor. Minha estrutura atual é a seguinte:

```
--- autores
    --- autores-create
        --- autores-create.component.html (página com o formulário para criação do novo autor)
        --- autores-create.component.ts
    --- shared
        --- autores.service.ts
    --- autor.model.ts
    --- autores.component.html (página principal com a tabela listando todos autores)
    --- autores.component.ts
    --- autores.module.ts
```

Código do autores.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { Autor } from './autor.model';
import { AutoresService } from './shared/autores.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-autores',
    templateUrl: './autores.component.html'
})
export class AutoresComponent implements OnInit {

    message: string;
    autores: Autor[];

    constructor(private service: AutoresService, private router: Router) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        // Chamando o serviço para listar todos os autores
        this.service.getAutores().subscribe(data => {
            this.autores = data;
        })

        // Me inscrevendo no EventEmitter do serviço para saber quando foi gerada nova mensagem
        this.service.message.subscribe(
            (data: string) => { alert(data); this.message = data; }
        );
    }

    removerAutor(id: number) {
        this.service.removerAutor(id).subscribe(resultado => this.autores = this.autores.filter(autores => autores.id !== id));
    }

    // Apenas navega para página com formulário de criação de novo autor
    criarAutor() {
        this.router.navigate(['autores/create']);
    }
}
```

Código do autores-create.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { Autor } from './../autor.model';
import { AutoresService } from '../shared/autores.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-autores-create',
    templateUrl: './autores-create.component.html'
})
export class AutoresCreateComponent implements OnInit {

    form: FormGroup;
    emailPattern: "^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$";

    constructor(private service: AutoresService, private route: Router) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.form = new FormGroup({
            'nome': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
            'endereco': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)]),
            'email': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
        })
    }

    // Chama o método de criação de novo autor no serviço e quando finaliza navega para a página inicial com a tabela
    criarAutor(data: Autor) {
        this.service.criarAutor(data).subscribe((data) => {
            this.route.navigate(['/autores']);
        });
    }

    campoInvalido(campo: string) {
        if (this.form.get(campo).invalid && (this.form.get(campo).dirty || this.form.get(campo).touched)) {
            return this.form.get(campo).errors;
        }
    }
}
```

Código do autores.service.ts

```
import { Injectable, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Autor } from '../autor.model';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AutoresService {

    API_URL: string = 'http://localhost:3000';
    // Campo de mensagem que seria exibida na página da tabela indicando que o novo autor foi criado com sucesso
    @Output() message: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'my-auth-token'
        })
    };

    getAutores(): Observable<Autor[]> {
        return this.http.get<Autor[]>(`${this.API_URL}/autores`)
            .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
    }

    removerAutor(id: number) {
        return this.http.delete(`${this.API_URL}/autores/${id}`, this.httpOptions)
            .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
    }

    criarAutor(dados: Autor) {
        // Emissão do evento ao criar novo autor
        this.message.emit("Autor criado com sucesso.")
        return this.http.post(`${this.API_URL}/autores`, dados, this.httpOptions)
            .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
    }

    private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
        if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
            // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
            console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
        } else {
            // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
            // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
            console.error(
                `Backend returned code ${error.status}, ` +
                `body was: ${error.error}`);
        }
        // return an observable with a user-facing error message
        return throwError(
            'Something bad happened; please try again later.');
    };
}
```

Código do autores.component.html

```
<div class="container py-5">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 mb-5 d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            <h1 class="d-inline">Autores</h1>
            <button (click)="criarAutor()" class="btn btn-success">+ autor</button>
        </div>

        <!-- Aqui deveria aparecer a mensagem -->
        <div class="alert alert-success">{{ message }}</div>

        <div class="col-md-12">
            <table *ngIf="autores?.length > 0" class="table" style="table-layout: fixed;">
                <thead>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Nome</th>
                    <th>Ações</th>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                    <tr *ngFor="let autor of autores">
                        <td>{{ autor.id }}</td>
                        <td>{{ autor.nome }}</td>
                        <td>
                            <button class="btn btn-warning mr-3">Editar</button>
                            <button (click)="removerAutor(autor.id)" class="btn btn-danger">Remover</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

            <p *ngIf="autores?.length === 0">Não existem autores cadastrados.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

O que achei mais estranho é que no arquivo autores.component.ts, especificamente neste trecho de código:

```
this.service.message.subscribe(
            (data: string) => { alert(data); this.message = data; }
        );
```

O alert está funcionando corretamente mas a mensagem não é trocada! Alguém teria alguma sugestão? Gostaria de fazer isso sem utilização de bibliotecas prontas para fixar meu aprendizado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não sei se é o caso, mas aqui está o código do autores.module.ts

```
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http'
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AutoresService } from './shared/autores.service';

import { AutoresComponent } from './autores.component';
import { AutoresCreateComponent } from './autores-create/autores-create.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [AutoresComponent, AutoresCreateComponent],
    imports: [CommonModule, HttpClientModule, RouterModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
    providers: [AutoresService]
})

export class AutoresModule { }
```

E por último, aqui o conteúdo do meu app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AutoresModule } from './autores/autores.module';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './components/header/header.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        HeaderComponent,
        HomeComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AutoresModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        RouterModule
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Então quando vc diz: **O alert está funcionando corretamente mas a mensagem não é trocada!**, o alerta com certeza vai ser disparado pq está no `NgOnInit()` e quando o componente é renderizado o Angular automaticamente chama esse método. Acho que o erro talvez possa ser esse **eventEmitter** pq ele funciona para fazer comunicação do componente filho para o componente pai, mas, pela hierarquia que colocou na pergunta, todos os componentes são irmãos um dos outros.

Comment: Sim mas o alert está dentro do subscribe, não solto no NgOnInit().. Ou seja, eu só estou vendo aquele alert depois de ir na página do formulário e dar submit nele.. e o alerta está vindo com a mensagem certa, a variable data. Jogando essa data no meu this.message é que nada acontece.